# Error using skipLocationChange in anchor tag

Tags: angular, angular14

I'm attempting to add skipLocationChange property to inline archer tag. I have found multiple sources that stated to format it like below.

```
<a routerLink='toolpanel' skipLocationChange></a>
```

Doing so generates the error below.

```
error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

<li (click)='switchActive($event);'><a routerLink='toolpanel' skipLocationChange></a></li>
```

If I remove the skipLocationChange property, then everything works with not issue. I know I can use a function and set the router.navigate option, but I would prefer to use the inline anchor 'property' if possible. Is there a fix I'm missing or do I have to go the function to router.navigate direction?

Comment: Try [skipLocationChange]=“true” maybe?

Comment: @MikeOne Yep, that was it. I tried skipLocationChange=“true” and it didn't work.  In all the examples I saw, none used the brackets. Added brackets and it's golden. Post solution for check sir!